# trigger ng-bootstrap accordion component with typescript(javascript)?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, ng-bootstrap

Im using [ng-bootstrap framework](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) in my Angular 4 project.

I have 'accordion' components in multiple places in my application and in some cases I need to trigger accordion open state in typescript.

From the [accordion component API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/api) I found following method, but as far as I have tried it only works when called in html file (tried calling from constructor).

```
//Programmatically toggle a panel with a given id.
toggle(panelId: string) => void
```

Should it also be possible to trigger in typescript?
If anybody has experience with it I would be really thankful. Otherwise I need to build my own custom accordions.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

for this you have to use `ViewChild` strong typed with `NgbAccordion` component.

You can do same thing with any components of ng-boostrap and any public method of any child Component.

Step to follow :

1/ add #someIdentifier to your component tag in html side.

2/ Use `@ViewChild('someIdentifier')` to make reference on your `component.ts`

3/ StrongCast your attribute by the ComponentType.

4/ Enjoy any public method from your Child Component.

Following example :

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbAccordion} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-accordion-toggle',
  templateUrl: './accordion-toggle.html'
})
export class NgbdAccordionToggle {
  @ViewChild('acc') accordionComponent: NgbAccordion;

  // Method call on click.
  toggle(id:string): void {
  //Here you have access to AccordionComponent as discribe on documentation.    
    this.accordionComponent.toggle(id);
  }
}
```

Html side :

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion">
// [...]
</ngb-accordion>
```

Live example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-szhpdw?file=app%2Faccordion-toggle.ts

Comment: NgbAccordion is deprecated since 14.1.0 since it now directives based (not component)